# Dropdown menu on mouse hover with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a very annoying problem, and it is bugging me for some time now, and I've tried everything to fix it, but I simply fail at doing so.

The problem is: I have a navigation which consists of many `<div>` elements inside `<div>`, which is inside another `<div>` and so on.

**Here is the code for my navigation:**

```
    <div class="nav-laptop"><a href="proizvodi.php?upit=SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='Laptop' ORDER BY Proizvodac Asc;">Laptop</a><br />

  <div class="nav-bot"><a href="proizvodi.php?upit=SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='Laptop' AND Proizvodac='Acer' ORDER BY Proizvodac ASC;">Acer</a></div>
  <br />
  <div class="nav-bot"><a href="proizvodi.php?upit=SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='Laptop' AND Proizvodac='Apple' ORDER BY Proizvodac ASC;">Apple</a></div>
  <br />
  <div class="nav-bot"><a href="proizvodi.php?upit=SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='Laptop' AND Proizvodac='Asus' ORDER BY Proizvodac ASC;">Asus</a></div>
  <br />
  <div class="nav-bot"><a href="proizvodi.php?upit=SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='Laptop' AND Proizvodac='Dell' ORDER BY Proizvodac ASC;">Dell</a></div>
  <br />
  <div class="nav-bot"><a href="proizvodi.php?upit=SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='Laptop' AND Proizvodac='HP' ORDER BY Proizvodac ASC;">HP</a></div>
  <br />
  <div class="nav-bot"><a href="proizvodi.php?upit=SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='Laptop' AND Proizvodac='Lenovo' ORDER BY Proizvodac ASC;">Lenovo</a></div>
  <br />
  <div class="nav-bot"><a href="proizvodi.php?upit=SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='Laptop' AND Proizvodac='Toshiba' ORDER BY Proizvodac ASC;">Toshiba</a></div>
</div>
```

**I will attach a picture to give you a better view on what I have:**
[image: Here the first dropdown nav you see is the code above, and all others are completely the same, only contain more data. The dropdown is animated with CSS3.]

**Now here is my CSS for those navigation `<div>`s:**

```
    .nav-laptop, .nav-pc, .nav-tablet, .nav-periferije, .nav-dijelovi, .nav-audio, .nav-mobitel, .nav-monitor, .nav-televizor, .nav-usluge {
    transition: height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
    height: 20px;
    width: 72px;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    -ms-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    -o-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #F00;
    font-size: 1.05em;
    margin-top: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**And here is :hover version for laptop nav only:**

```
    .nav-laptop:hover {
    height: 186px;
    width: 72px;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    -ms-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    -o-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1.05em;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

Now this all navigation works awesome and beautiful and everything, but the problem is, whenever I hover with my mouse over any category, when the division drops down, it distorts all the content below, and makes a huge mess, and once I move my mouse, it all gets back to normal.
How should I go about it? This may be very inefficient way to do it, and I'm open to all suggestions, and looking forward to learning more from you people.

**Here's a normal content:**
[image]

**And here's distorted content due to hovering onto navigation:**
[image]

Comment: Could you provide us with a link?

Comment: Sure thing.
http://manjaric-dorian.ssdr.avalon.hr/Zavrsni/index.php

Comment: FWIW, you dont need any of those vendor prefixes anymore - compatibility for border-radius and transition is now there on every browser.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for clearing that up. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are floating the "dropdown" parts of the menu. And if all the rest of the content are also floating, all the things are in the same flow. Thus they get all "weird", even though this is not at all weird but rather exactly the expected behavior.

Instead, you should be using absolute positioning for the parts that you want to overlay on the other content. Absolute positioning removes the element from the document flow, and thus is does not affect the layout of anything else other than itself.

So, make the "dropdown" parts `position: absolute` and the main menu items `position: relative`, for example. This way the "dropdown" parts will get positioned relative to the main menu items.

Take a look at e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp or http://learnlayout.com for basic CSS layout tutorials.

**Simple example of a hover menu:**

```css
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
li ul li {
  background: #eee  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>First</span>
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Second</span>
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
  <p>Content content content content content content content<br>content content content content content content...</p>
  <p>Content content content content content content content<br>content content content content content content...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @BloodDrunk I've added a very simple example.

Comment: Thank you sir, this fixed my problem! It now works as intended.

Comment: @BloodDrunk Great, please accept the answer so that your question does not remain unanswered in the system. Also, what comes to your insecure database query, you might want to google something like "PHP safe MySQL query" or something similar to learn more about it, let's try to keep one question for one topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would play around with `position:absolute;` and `z-index`.

A normal way to do this is to use `<ul>` lists.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Hover</a>
        <ul>
            <li>asdasd</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul li:hover ul{display:block;}
/* or ul li a + ul{display:block} */

ul li > a{position:relative;}
ul ul{display:absolute;display:none;}
```

Offtopic:

```
proizvodi.php?upit=SELECT Slika, Naziv, Opis, Cijena FROM Proizvodi WHERE Kategorija='Laptop' AND Proizvodac='Toshiba' ORDER BY Proizvodac ASC;
```

Are you allowing a script to execute sql through a GET parameter? :O

Comment: How would you play around with `position` and `z-index`?

Comment: Yes, I am. I've heard that not the safest way to do it. Actually it's not safe at all, and should be avoided as far as I've been told, but since this is for school project, it is okay to do it. :)
POST is the way, right?

Comment: Nope. You should do something like `giveme.php?query=query2`. And on the server-side `if( $_GET['query'] == 'query2' ) return something;`. What whould happen if I requested `proizvodi.php?upit=DROP TABLE Proizvodi`

Comment: You would destroy my entire table.
I did not really understand this second part, can you give me a step by step to avoid that vurnerability? I'm after all just a begginer in this, and I want to learn proper ways of doing it.
I have made a backup of my table just in case someone is as evil to destroy it..

Comment: @BloodDrunk Just Google "SQL Injection for beginners"